# Maximo anywhere error - No runtime environment deployed to this server'

Tags: javascript, json, maximo-anywhere

On logging in the worklight console , we are getting the error 'No runtime environment deployed to this server' . 
We have deployed the runtime war directly in websphere instead of using.
MobileFirst configuration tool and clicking on 'Add a MobileFirst runtime environment to a configuration'.

This approach is working fine in development environment but not working in higher environment.

Pls help me if there is any configuration missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to restart your worklight server, or deploy using the mobilefirst server configuration tool. If the version of the worklight components used to compile the war file doesn’t match the server components this can happen.

Comment: Hi Kasey..thanks for your answer.we can not deploy using mobile first server configuration tool due to some restrictions in client environment. Can we tweak the war file and re deploy in server?. Pls help me What exactly to be done to match the versions of worklight components and server components.

Comment: Thanks for your reply kasey. Unfortunately we can not use mobile first server config tool ..we have to deploy the war manually.  Could you pls help me understans what exactly to be done to match the versions of worklight components and server components to avoid this error.